# Convert Kinetic.js Canvas to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, kineticjs

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out the best way to convert my Kinetic.js canvas to a PDF file? I thought when researching which canvas to use I saw something that could do this, but I can't seem to find it now.

Much Appreciated

***EDIT
After trying jsPDF and trying to follow their examples I'm still having problems. Here is my code:
I've tried jsPDF and can't get it to work for some reason even though I follow the tutorials. Here is my code if you don't mind looking at it. (The html and most of the javascript is just from the Kineticjs tutorial, I just added a method at the end to turn it into a PDF which isn't working.)

for some reason it returns "img" as undefined and says 
"TypeError: doc.addImage is not a function".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSPDF\jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSPDF\jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSPDF\jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>               
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JSPDF\jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jspdf.plugin.addImage.js"></script>

    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script defer="defer">
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius: 70,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(circle);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);


    function toPDF()
      {


        var img=stage.toDataURL("image/jpeg");          
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        console.log(img);
        doc.setFontSize(22);
        doc.text(20, 20, 'This is a exmaple of jsPDF');
        doc.addImage(img,'JPEG', 10, 10, 50, 50);
        doc.save('test.pdf');
        doc.output('datauri');

      }



    </script>
    <button id="button" onClick="toPDF()">Click </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

for some reason it returns "img" as undefined and says 
"TypeError: doc.addImage is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

A canvas drawing in KineticJS can be exported to a .png (or .jpg) image using stage.toDataURL().

```
var stagePNG = stage.toDataURL();
```

You can embed that image (along with any other info desired) in a PDF using an app like jsPDF:

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried jsPDF and can't get it to work for some reason even though I follow the tutorials. Here is my code if you don't mind looking at it.

Comment: jsPDF only supports jpeg for now. var stagePNG = stage.toDataURL('image/jpeg',1.0);

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this thread, I got it working by doing the following, hope it helps someone. Use the following (**Don't forget to apply** `id="savePdf"` **to a button**) :

```
document.getElementById('savePdf').addEventListener('click', function() {
    stage.toDataURL({
    mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    quality: 1.0,
     callback: function(dataUrl) {
        var imgData = dataUrl
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
      }
    });
  }, false);
```